# How to combine duplicate data points into a array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

What I am trying to do is use the current_product_id and if there are multiple duplicates in my CSV file, I want to add the related_product_id into an array with no more duplicate current_product_id. I have tried using table and aggregates, but I am not sure if it is being used correctly.
[image: before/after situation]

```
db.testing1.aggregate([   
  {     "$unwind": "$related_product_id"   },   
  {     "$group": {"_id": "$related_product_id[0]",       
         "count": {"$sum": 1}   },   
  {     "$match": {"_id": {$in: ["$related_product_id"]}}   }, 
])
```

Nothing happens when I enter this into my shell once I log into MongoDB. My MongoDB still looks like the before picture.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

sample document

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    _id: "A",
    current: 1,
    related: [
      23
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    _id: "B",
    current: 1,
    related: [
      25
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    _id: "C",
    current: 1,
    related: [
      31
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 4,
    _id: "D",
    current: 2,
    related: [
      25
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 1,
    _id: "E",
    current: 2,
    related: [
      23
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    _id: "F",
    current: 3,
    related: [
      25
    ]
  },
  
]
```

Code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$related"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$current",
      current: {
        $first: "$current"
      },
      key: {
        $first: "$key"
      },
      related: {
        $push: "$related"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "current": 3,
    "key": 2,
    "related": [
      25
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "current": 1,
    "key": 1,
    "related": [
      23,
      25,
      31
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "current": 2,
    "key": 4,
    "related": [
      25,
      23
    ]
  }
]
```

Try [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ykxIY0fCZ84)

Comment: When I try to add that into my mongoshell it does not do the same thing as in mongoplayground.

link to what happens when I use the same query command in Mongo shell
[link](https://ibb.co/7NK5Lfn)

Link to mongo playground working exactly as I wanted it to.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/iNntz3myr8d